# Kafka Configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using Few properties of spring kafka in application.properties of an application like bootstrap servers ,auto-offset-reset,enable-auto-commit,serializer etc.

need to provide documentation of all the properties we have for this spring kafka or at least one URL where we have all the properties of spring kafka for both producer and consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client properties are all available in Kafka documentation

1. [Producer Config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs)
2. [Consumer Config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs)

Comment: But it is confluent Kafka right, but i need properties of spring Kafka for both producer and consumer

Comment: It is suitable for the spring. You must customise required properties with kafka producer and kafka consumer based on your requirements.

for example, for Kafka producer, you must config the following properties

1. bootstrap.servers
2. key.serializer
3. value.serializer

Comment: @jannathhussain The Kafka client properties aren't unique to Confluent. Read the spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka

Comment: then you can look at this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.0.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaProperties.java for supported properties.